# How to get value of property Speaks tuff on Model using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, html-helper

I work on asp.net MVC 5 .NET Framework . I face issue I can't get value of
Property SpeakStuff when catch Detail Action Result .

on object `ResignationRequester` property `SpeakStuff` represent by two check boxes Yes and No .

if `SpeakStuff` equal True then Yes checkbox will be checked

if `SpeakStuff` equal False then No checkbox will be checked

so How to do that when catch Detail Action Result

my code as below :

```
<div> 
@Html.Label("Did You Meet/Speak to Staff", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
  <div class="col-md-7">
      <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="true" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") />
      Yes
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="checkbox" id="SpeakStuff" name="SpeakStuff" value="false" class="speak-stuff-checkbox" @(!Model.SpeakStuff ? "checked" : "") />
      No
  </div>
</div>

 $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
     $('.speak-stuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     $('#SpeakStuff').val(selectedValue);
 });
  public class ResignationRequester
  {

   public bool SpeakStuff { get; set; }
  }
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id, string msg)
{
  
    ResignationRequester workforceRequest = Workforce.ResignationGetRequestByID((int)id);
   
   //when check workforceRequest.SpeakStuff it will be true or false 
// so How to make check box yes checked when true and checkbox No checked when it False
    return View(workforceRequest);
}
```

so suppose `workforceRequest.SpeakStuff=false` then No will checked as Image below :
[image: image for checkbox checked]